# Deploy app on Heroku using Mariasql client and JawsDB Maria addon

Tags: node.js, mariadb, mariasql

I am deploy my node app on Heroku using Mariasql and JawsDB Maria addon.

Above is my code

```
const Client = require('mariasql');
const connection = new Client({
    host: process.env.hostname || packageJsonDbConfig.host,
    port: process.env.port || packageJsonDbConfig.port,
    user: process.env.userName,
    password: process.env.password,
    db: process.env.dbName || packageJsonDbConfig.dbName,
    multiStatements: true
});
```

My connection string format on Heroku for JawDB Maria is like this
mysql://username:password@hostname:port/default_schema

I already add the host, port, user, password, dbName to my Config Vars on Heroku, but I kept getting

```
Error: Access denied for user 'wd3digda5hp2ndmd'@'ec2-54-87-49-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
```

Any help will be appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on @, in the error message it isn't correct with the '. So it may need to be escaped or you defined it in a wrong way.